# Why is the route not finding the the decimal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rails-routing

Ok so i have an application that i use this jquery

```
$("#band_events").load("/load_events/"+ escape($('#request_artist').val()), successCallback );
```

It works great but if #request_artist is R.E.M. or somehthing with decimals or something weird rails has problems like

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/load_events/R.E.M." with {:method=>:get}):
```

here is my routes line

```
map.load_events '/load_events/:band', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'load_events'
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
map.connect ... , :constraints => { :band => /.*/ }
```

(Or any other pattern of your taste.) [About constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)

It doesn't seem to be working in all versions of rails, though. I'm pretty sure I used this trick before, but can't get it to work now. So, good luck with it.

Comment: FYI, replace `:band` with your route parameter name. That one got me for a bit. I thought `:band` was something special.

Answer (score 1):

To escape a URL you should use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape`.

Comment: this still failing  /load_events/R.E.M.

Comment: No route matches "/load_events/R.E.M." with {:method=>:get}